# Left align with printf in bash with unknown width

Tags: bash, printf, leftalign

I am trying to left align with printf in bash with unknown width.

How do I do so?

So sort of like this, but this does not work

```sh
max=<enter random number>
printf "%-${max}s|", "Instance"
```

The point of this is the instance below will be an unknown length that can is dynamic in length.

Example Input

```
max=10
```

Example Output

```
Instance  |
```

Example Input2

```
max=12
```

Example Output2

```
Instance    |
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Ok Cyrus I added example outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `*` for the length:

```
for ((max=8;max<15;max++)); do
    printf "%-*s|\n" ${max} "Instance"
done
```

Result:

```
Instance|
Instance |
Instance  |
Instance   |
Instance    |
Instance     |
Instance      |
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It was not working before when I used it because I had " awk 'BEGIN { printf ... }' " wrapped around it. There was no need for the awk BEGIN for my purpose so problem solved.

Comment: `awk` works too when you use `for ((max=8;max<15;max++)); do awk -v max=${max} 'BEGIN {printf("%-*s|\n", max, "Instance")}'; done`.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're trying to print a table. I think you won't be able to do this with `printf` alone. This would basically require your line outputting command to predict the future output.

If you can tolerate post-processing though, you can simply do it using the `column` command. Just pick a character you'd like to replace with padding, and do as in the following example (I've picked the backslash `\`):

```
printf "%s\\|\n" "Instance" "Linstance" "Mintinginstance" | column -ts'\'
```

Output:

> ```
> Instance         |
> Linstance        |
> Mintinginstance  |
> ```